# What is basic rule to create a bundle idetifier in iOS app

Tags: ios

I was attempting a online test. there is four option for "What is incorrect bundle id's". Option are -

```
1) com.companyName.appName
2) com.appName
3) appName
4) com.company-name.app-Name
```

I was confused , what will be the correct answer of this question. I have tried to find out, what is basic rule for creating a bundle id. But not got my satisfactory answer. Please help.

Comment: I always prefer first one:  com.companyName.appName

Comment: @SunnyShah : never use your company name... for iPhone its okay but when it comes to android and if client ask the link of the play store and if he see our company name they get irritated...

Comment: @FahimParkar But you can use client company name, that's up to you. But its important to use because any third person can know what kind of this app and for whom you are developing. so combination is always require. if client has no company you can still use his name

Comment: Yes @SunnyShah is correct. If your are developing an application for s client. Of course "CompanyName" would represent the client's company name and not the developer's company name. The standard is  com.companyName.appName. If client is an individual and does not belong to a company, even com.appName is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that contains only alphanumeric characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.). The string should be in reverse-DNS format. For example, if your organization’s domain is Abc.com and you create an app named xyz, you could assign the string com.xyz.Hello as your app’s bundle ID.

Comment: In this way, bundle id can be all the four options as mentioned in question. I am agree with your answer. But want to know as per my test result, According to test result bundle id can not be like com.appName. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: according to your question in my opinion option 1 will be the correct format for bundle Id